# QuerydslPredicate with PagingAndSortingRepository

Tags: spring, pagination, predicate, querydsl

I am new to learning `QueryDslPredicate` and `PagingAndSortingRepository`

I want to use use the predicate along with sorting and pagination in my findAll request. How can this be done ?

```
QTestOrder qTestOrder = QTestOrder.testOrder;
        BooleanExpression isUser = qTestOrder.user.eq(userDAO.getUserByPhone(Long.parseLong(params.getFirst(Constant.USER))));
        BooleanExpression isId = qTestOrder.id.eq(new Long(params.getFirst(Constant.ID)));
        BooleanExpression isStatus = qTestOrder.testStatus.eq(testStatusDAO.getByRank(Integer.parseInt(params.getFirst(Constant.STATUS))));

        testOrderRepo.findAll(isUser.or(isId).or(isStatus),qTestOrder.orderCreationTime.desc());
```

So above returns me list of testOrders, I now want to do pagination over the, using query like below . How do I return all paginated and sorted users based on my query. Is there any method for that or workaround ?

```
        Pageable page = new PageRequest(p, Constant.DEFAULT_PAGE_SIZE);
        Page<TestOrder> l = testOrderRepo.findAll(page);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can implement `QueryDslPredicateExecutor<T>` in your repository interfaces. This interface provides a method with following signature:

```
Page<T> findAll(Predicate predicate, Pageable pageable);
```

Which Returns a page of entities matching the given `Predicate`.

Suppose you have domain entity, say `TestOrder`, then you can define a `TestOrderRepository` like following:

```
public interface TestOrderRepository extends QueryDslPredicateExecutor<TestOrder> {}
```

and finally you can:

```
Pageable pagable = new QPageRequest(1, 10, your_order_specifier)
testOrderRepository.findAll(isUser.or(isId).or(isStatus), pageable);
```